# symfony2: how to set a user attribute (that is not in the form) after submitting a registration form?

Tags: symfony, symfony-forms

I have added an attribute "color" the the User class, so when a user is registered I want a random color is assigned to this user.

How to do this smartly?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Set it in the User class constructor.

You can find a good example of setting default values for a new user in the FOSUserBundle's User [constructor](https://github.com/FriendsOfSymfony/FOSUserBundle/blob/master/Model/User.php#L126).

One of the advantages of this approach is that you don't depend on a persistence layer events and it works without a persistence layer at all.

Answer (score 1):

I would add a lifecycle event in the User entity, a prePersist event.

Define in your user class the `setRandomColor` method, which set a color attribute of your User randomly.

Then, add it in your doctrine entity config as a prePersist event.

```
lifecycleCallbacks:
    prePersist: [ setRandomColor ]
```

Answer (score 0):

if you need your user color during a single session you can define an attribute for the user doing this:

```
$this->getUser()->setAttribute('attr-name',$attr-value);
```

and get that attribute with:

```
$this->getUser()->getAttribute('attr-name');
```

but, if you want to mantain the attribute as if it was an attribute in the user's table 
you can

- (obviously) update your schema and add the field in the table
- get the color using a [hash function](http://php.net/manual/en/book.hash.php) over the primary key of the user's table.

Good luck!